# How do you resolve the findRecord issue in buffered store for ExtJS 4.2

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2

There is a problem with the new upgrade of ExtJS 4.2 where the stores have been altered and findRecord does not work properly anymore. Any good solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use **findExact()** in combination with **getAt()**

Comment: What you could also do for the moment if you have to use this function is the following - implement a function in your controller called findRecord (for easier refactoring later on) and instead of calling grid.findRecord() call this.findRecord().

Comment: `findRecord: function(store, fieldName, value, startIndex) {..............................     var id, record;
    id = store.findExact(fieldName, value, startIndex);
    if (id >= 0) {
        return store.getAt(id);
    }
    return null;
}`